# How to create some points attach to an object using script?

Tags: scripting, objects

[image]

The question is I want to create some points which construct the area enclosed by brown lines in front for the sofa.This area is attached to the sofa and it will follow the action of sofa such as move or rotate.

How to realize it using script? Other packages are allowed.

Note that I have got OBB and orient of sofa, I'm thinking about scale OBB's bottom polygon as this rectangle.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "points"? Like which blender object types are you referring to? Empties? Vertices? Hooks?

Comment: All vertices.This question want to create vertices out of thin air that does not belong to any plane